# understanding electrical motor and force

Tags: high-voltage, capacitor-charging

I am looking to drive an electrical motor to power a cart with some substantial weight.
I want to power this with as simple a method as possible but want to maximise the force for it.
I have several 18650 cells I can use for the main power source and the intended motor runs on 12v dc from a scooter.
I would like to try and increase the output force of the motor whole decreasing the drain on the actual cells, to this end I was thinking that driving it with circuit similar to what is inside a dispisable camera which charges a 2000volt capacitor from a 1.5 volt battery,but am unsure how the magic works to do this.

1. would a capacitor from a microwave which is apx 9000uf at 2000v be able to work for this?
2. what aditional parts would I need to add in the circuit?
3. as the existing wiring gets quite hot as is I fear overheating the motor and burning it up,could  such a method reduce the heat caused by this or would it make matters worse?
4. would I be able to make the system easier by using instead the microwave oven transformer with some sort of pwm or other transistor run by an 18650 setup?

Comment: Typical Golf carts and those used by studios to move people about run on 48 VDC. 48 volt Chargers and 48 volt to 12 volt converters for lights and stereo are common off-the-shelf available, as are the electric motors and 48 volt batteries.

Comment: I am trying to focus on using parts I already have in creating my cart,I already have substantial electrical components from microwaves and the like arduinos and motors and tv components....I plan on using bike parts to build the cart....I really just want more understanding on how these components work so I can apply it best

Comment: Sounds like you have lots of parts, but they are not compatible with each other. How to make them compatible and discard that which can never work will be a trial-by-fire for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are assuming you are talking about the flash circuit in a disposable camera. The principle there is that the very low voltage from the battery is used to charge up the large photo-flash capacitor to provide a very large voltage/current to the Xenon flash tube.  Note, however that this provides power for only a very few milliseconds (ms, thousandths of one second).  And it takes a few seconds for the little battery to charge up that capacitor again for another flash lasting a very few ms.

But supplying power to a relatively large load like a motor is completely different than the momentary spike it takes to arc across a flash tube.  The electronics it takes to operate an electric vehicle are remarkable sophisticated in order to optimize the power flow from the battery to the motor(s).  Because electric vehicles are still in early stages, and using rather primitive battery cells.

Certainly, you should do the experiment to MEASURE how much voltage and current your proposed motor will take under typical operating conditions.  After you have those numbers, you can evaluate different methods of controlling the power flow between your battery and your motor.

Comment: I have quite limited access to test equiptment. I did a test by running the motor continuously for about an hour on a 3s3p pack before speeds notably dropped but this was with no load resisting it.I do hear about pwm as a means to get better performance for longevity but presume the higher voltages of the cap could increase torq

Comment: Even an inexpensive voltage/current meter from Ebay for <US$10 would be a must-have piece of test equipment if you expect to do any kind of experimenting. And the test must be performed under the design load. A no-load test doesn't really prove anything. Adding a capacitor(s) to this circuit doesn't really provide ANY benefit.

Comment: sorry am new to this process. I do have a cheap multimeter from ebay but could not figure out how exactly to use it for capacitance/amperage as the thing just seems to spew random numbers not even hooked to anything....suspect its damaged....I had originally hooked it directly to some 18650 cells to try to figure out the total ampers but got this problem....

Comment: am still not prepared to do a load test on this motor speciffic to this application as I am still in the concept/design phase off my cart....I know I am planning on using a bike rim attached to a larger bike tire as my drive system and weight will be substantial, that is why I am trying to see ways to increase torq and speed

Comment: Speed is a matter of the design/selection of the motor. And whatever gearing or mechanical transmission you use. Increasing torque is simply a matter of using a larger motor and more battery to operate it. There is no magic electrical way to increase either speed or torque.   It sounds like you probably fried your meter. You might want to study some YouTube videos on how to use a DMM before frying another one. I found 30V, 100A meters on Ebay for <$4 with free shipping from Hong Kong.

Comment: thanks. I was under the impression that if I could increase the voltage/amperage on the system I could increase the output of the motor...doing so in bursts via pwm I presumed would allow me to reduce heat as not as much total power would be consumed as the off phases would reduce it.hence having 2000v cap but still not sure how this can be saturated by the lower source?

Comment: note the cap would not need to be fully saturated but is being used as a sort of spring to ramp up the discharge voltages durring pwm off

Comment: You can "trade" voltage for current (and vice-versa). But you cannot "create" more power.  Yes, PWM can provide smoother control over speed variations, but it cannot INCREASE voltage or current (or power or speed).  PWM assumes you have maximum voltage/current already available from your battery. It cannot create it where it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39870/discussion-between-richard-crowley-and-firobug).

Answer (score 1):

> would a capacitor from a microwave which is apx 9000uf at 2000v be
>   able to work for this?

No, it would be completely useless. Despite its size, a microwave oven capacitor can only store a small amount of charge at 12V (certainly not enough to run a scooter motor). But even if you could somehow use this charge to boost the voltage, it still wouldn't magically increase the power available.

> as the existing wiring gets quite hot as is I fear overheating the
>   motor and burning it up

The wiring is getting hot because the current draw is too high for it, and possibly also too high for the motor.

You can reduce motor current by lowering the voltage (either using a lower voltage battery or by applying PWM) but that will also reduce torque. Motor torque is proportional to current. The only way to reduce current *and* increase torque is to gear the motor down. A gearbox (or belt and pulley set) allows the motor to spin faster so it draws less current, and also magnifies the output torque. It does this by trading rpm for torque, just like a lever trades distance for force.

If no gear ratio provides the combination of torque and speed that you want then the motor simply isn't powerful enough to do the job.

However in your case the limiting factor may actually be your batteries and wiring. Scooter motors are quite powerful, but draw a lot of current. Power = Volts x Amps, so a 12V 100W motor would need 8.3A to get maximum power. Most 18650 cells are rated for a maximum of 5A or less.

Comment: re battery pack used I was using a 3s3p arrangement bridged at each junction to make the whole a 12v 15 ah battery....

Comment: from what im seeing you all are saying the only thing that truely affects the forces of the motor are the direct watts per pulse ie a 12v 2a battery would be exactly the same as a 24v 1a

Comment: Assuming his 3s3p battery uses 3.7Vnom by 3A 18650 cells, if he discharges them down to 50% of max capacity (which is safe & good for life cycle longevity) then he will likely not get more than 11.1Vnom x ~3A *.5 = ~16.65 Wh of usable energy.  I have a small scooter that has a 240 Wh lead-acid battery pack (2*12V*10Ah, connected in series for 24V*10Ah=240Wh*.20=48Wh of usable energy).  The LA battery provides ~15 minutes of ride time @ 17 mph for a <=150 lb rider.  That's roughly 3.2 Wh/minute of ride time.  I would suggest a batt that is 48V and 100Wh of usable capacity.

Comment: @Firobug motor 'force' (torque) is proportional to current, so 2A at 12V would produce more 'force' than 1A at 24V. However if you geared the motor 2:1 then it would still only produce half the torque (and twice the rpm) but the gearbox would double the torque and halve the speed. Benefit is the motor would run cooler at the lower current.